# Getting click position on a sphere's texture with ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

Currently: I have a sphere with a texture on it that rotates around the y axis. I also have the position that was clicked in 3D space, as well as the rotated position on the sphere (I think).

Goal: Get the position on the texture, for example: I want to get what square of the image I click on. (See Example Sphere and image below)

---

In practice, I won't be using this image but I felt it would be a good starting point.

Code For getting position on the sphere based on [this example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html):

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        console.log(intersects[ 0 ].point);
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );

        var axis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
        var angle = objects[ 0 ].rotation.y;

        //Rotate Point
        intersects[ 0 ].point = vector.applyAxisAngle( axis, angle );

        console.log(intersects[ 0 ].point);
    }
}
```

Sphere:

[image: Sphere]

Image Wrapping it:
[image: Image Wrap]

Comment: hint: can you get the UV coords of the point you clicked on the sphere?

Comment: Im not really sure what UV is, I know it has to do with textures (UV Map), I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question, Im looking at the wiki link for UV Mapping https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UV_mapping and it mentions `For any point P on the sphere, calculate \hat d, that being the unit vector from P to the sphere's origin.` If the sphere is centered at 0,0 - Does that mean `P == D` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to calculate anything. `intersects[0].uv` gives you the the UV coordinates.

Texture coordinates range always from `0.0` to `1.0`. They are unitless. So same texture with another resolution will fit as well.
[image: UV coordinates]

So, if you need to know the pixel position of your click, do:

```
var pixelX = Math.round(intersects[0].uv.x * textureWidth);
var pixelY = Math.round(intersects[0].uv.y * textureHeight);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I took ages to get back to you but this is exactly what I needed